# SQL=INSERT INTO `#__user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`) VALUES (, 2) -- database was not updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, joomla

I have responsibility of a Joomla! 3.5.1 website. New users are added by a script in which an 'operator' may add a member. However, recently I have encountered a problem where the message, " SQL=INSERT INTO `#__user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`) VALUES (, 2) -- database was not updated" is returned.

I have looked in the JFacotry API & found the module 'com_users" holds the script which makes the BIND with all data for the `Params` & then passes it to SQL for execution of an INSERT INTO statement for the `#__user_usergroup_map` table.

However, I don't see the SQL statement in the execution of the code. but $user->getError certainly returns a SQL error.

My understanding of the problem, the code is not providing a user `id` as one of the 2 required variables for the INSERT INTO statement. When the process works, the code generates a new user `id` & provides it into the SQL statement.

This has worked in the past since we were using Joomla! 1.5. Now we are moving to Joomla! 3.5.1 but want to maintain the same member addition methodology.

Is there some special constraints upon the `#__user_usergroup_map` table that are not in place?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

> You must use the mark **'** and user_id value is auto increment values empty.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `__user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`) VALUES ('', '2')");
```

Comment: Thank you, but we seem to miscommunication. First of all, I don't see the SQL code whatsoever. It is being generated somewhere, but I have not found the file in the component which generates this code.

Comment: Thank you, we seem to not be communicating. 1st, I don't see the SQL code whatsoever. It is being generated somewhere, but I have not found the file in the component which generates this SQL code. 2nd Which tables need to be set to AUTO_INCREMENT? `users`, `user_usergroup_map` or something else? All I have found has been the PHP using the BIND and SAVE but I don't see the INSERT INTO command anywhere within the script. I think it is deep in the "com_users" component, but opening each file & looking through every file has not produced any result for me. I am adding the ` mark. Can you help?

Comment: I am sorry, but what code is not being sent? Are you asking for the code in my program? Please clarify.

Comment: I solved my own problem. But it wasn't for lack of a ' mark. The SQL code is not something I can even locate to edit. I am running the com_users component which has no visible SQL code to edit. If the ' mark has been omitted, I would have to find the SQL code to insert it. There are some ` marks in the PHP code, however, when I place it into the StackOverFlow's forum, quotation marks (") & single quotation marks (') are changed. Database field & table names get changed to light blue highlighted text. The ' mark was in my information, just the responder could not see it. The code executes.

Comment: Does anyone know where the SQL code is for the 'com_users' component may be found? I would like to add another SQL INSERT INTO statement to the script.